# How to create the audit database tables using Entity Framework Provider?

Tags: audit.net

I'm trying to implement Audit.Net with Entity Framework, I need to create an audit table for each of my current tables and add some fields. Do I have to create all the audit entities like my actual ones and add a Migration to create it all in database? Doesn't it have some dynamic way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework/README.md) does not provide any dynamic way to generate migrations for audit tables. If you have any idea on how to provide this, feel free to [open a new issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new/choose) and add your suggestions.

Comment: I've already implemented it, but the hard part was generating my entities all again, mapping the properties correclty to what I wanted, and implementing an interface with the aditional fields to create the tables correctly. At the moment I have no idea of how to solve this but thats something interesting to work on.